# MongoDB: Query has implicit limit(256)?

Tags: java, mongodb, clojure

I've created (in code) a default collection in MongoDB and am querying it, and have discovered that while the code will return all the data when I run it locally, it won't when I query it on a deployment server. It returns a maximum of 256 records.

Notes:

- This is not a capped collection.
- Locally, I'm running 3.2.5, the remote MongoDB version is 2.4.12
- I am not using the limit parameter. When I use it, I can limit both the local and deployment server, but the deployment server will still never return more than 256 records.
- The amount of data being fetched from the server is <500K. Nothing huge.
- The code is in Clojure, using Monger, which itself just calls the Java com.mongodb stuff.

  - I can pull in more than 256 records from the remote server using Robomongo though I'm not sure how it does this, as I cannot connect to the remote from the command line (auth failed using the same credentials, so I'm guessing version incompatibility there).

Any help is appreciated.

UPDATE: Found the thing that triggers the problem: When I sort the output, it reduces the output to 256—but only when I pull from Mongo 2.4! I don't know if this is a MongoDB itself, the MongoDB java class, or Monger, but here is the code that illustrates the issue, as simple as I could make it:

```
(ns mdbtest.core
  (:require [monger.core :as mg]
            [monger.query :as mq]))

(defn get-list []
  (let [coll (mq/with-collection
               (mg/get-db
                 (mg/connect {:host "old-mongo"}) "mydb") "saves"
               (mq/sort (array-map :createdDate -1)))]   ;;<<==remove sort
    coll))
```

Comment: Can you share bit of code so that we might be able to reproduce the issue ourselves?

Comment: Whoomp. There it is.

Comment: I see this on my 2.4 instance of MongoDB with clojure and monger. However on the same instance it seems that the mongo command line works fine: `db.photos.find( { keywords: "lisa" }).sort( { datetime: 1} ).count()` `688`

Answer (score 1):

You need to specify a bigger batch-size, the default is 256 records.

Here's an example from my own code:

```
=> (count (with-db (q/find {:keywords "lisa"}) 
                  (q/sort {:datetime 1}) ))
256

=> (count (with-db (q/find {:keywords "lisa"}) 
                  (q/sort {:datetime 1}) 
                  (q/batch-size 1000) ))
688
```

See more info here: http://clojuremongodb.info/articles/querying.html#setting_batch_size

Comment: If I ever get back to verify this (it was not quite 2 years ago when the problem emerged) I'll green-check you. =P

Comment: Fair enough :) BTW, I only saw it on 2.4 on my Raspberry Pi.